# Trouble opening a MDF database file

Tags: sql-server, mdf

I am having trouble opening a file that's in SQL Server. Have already tried Excel where it said that the application was unable to start correctly.

I thought that this file would be able to work in Access but that option does not appear when trying to open the file.

Any tips/ help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a **SQL Server** database and you need to use some form of the **SQL Server** database engine (in Express, Web, Developer, Standard, Enterprise edition) to attach it and look into it

Comment: You need to open SQL Express or SQL Server and "Attach' an MDF file...

Comment: You don't "open" an `mdf` file. `mdf` files, along with their appropriate `ldf` file, are attached to a running SQL Server instance. [Attach a Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15)